# New Object not triggering createRecord in DataSource

Tags: sproutcore

In my responder I have:

```
Spanish.ADDWORD = SC.Responder.create({

  didBecomeFirstResponder: function(responder) {
    var store = this._store = Spanish.store.chain(); //buffer changes
    var word = store.createRecord(Spanish.Word, {word: "", english: ""});
    Spanish.addWordController.set("content",word);

    //show the dialog
    var pane = Spanish.getPath('addWordPage.mainPane');
    pane.append();
    pane.makeFirstResponder();
  },      

  submit: function(){
    this._store.commitChanges().destroy();
    Spanish.makeFirstResponder(Spanish.READY);
  }
}
```

Before I had the DataSource hooked-up, and I was using local, everything worked. When I click submit now no new object is created and createRecord is not being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible problem is that you are calling .destroy() immediately. This shouldn't be an issue, but as you said it was working while using fixtures (which are synchronous). Now that you are using a dataSource (which is usually asynchronous), it may be getting interrupted. Try removing the .destory(), and see if that resolves your issue.

Another option to try, is that there may be a bug in the nested store, in that if you create a new record (rather than edit an existing one), the 'did it change' test may fail (as there is nothing to compair it too), so calling `commitChanges(YES)` will force a commit, without the check.